# latest appengine-gcs-client lib produces GCS Java API deprecation warning

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

The GCS files api is turned down on July 28th, 2015. 
In my development server I got the following warning:

> The Google Cloud Storage Java API is deprecated and will soon be removed. Please use the Google Cloud Storage Client library instead. Migration documentation is available here: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/googlecloudstorageclient/migrate

I have downloaded the latest version of the **appengine-gcs-client** from the git repository referenced in the official migration documentation. But I still got the warning in my dev server. 
I checked all my dependencies but it seems that the only reference to the files api is located inside the appengine-gcs-client library itself. It is used in **LocalRawGcsService.java** (which I think is used in the dev server only).

As I have not seen a deprecation warning in my productive logs I think I do not have a problem, but I seriously wonder why they annoy me with that warning.

- Am I missing something important?
- Will I be able to use the **appengine-gcs-client** library in my productive environment and/or in my dev server after they have turned down the service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're not using `com.google.appengine.api.files.FileService`, you don't need to worry. You're correct to note that this is still apparently used by that local class in the GCS client libary. There's a [currently-open issue](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-gcs-client/issues/14) on the github project to get that addressed.

So, feel free to ignore that warning.

Comment: Thanks Nick, you are right. Today Google has turned down the files api service for an hour. I haven't had any log warnings in my productive system and as expected the system has worked fine during the turndown.

Answer (score 0):

Just for completeness: Beginning with Google App Engine Java SDK 1.9.28 the files api is disabled in the development server. 
In Version 0.5+ of the appengine-gcs-client library the files api was replaced. The library now works fine. It could be downloaded here: http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.appengine.tools/appengine-gcs-client